# Without excluded middle: simple example of field with nilpotents?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, field-theory, topos-theory, constructive-mathematics

I would like to verify I'm not making a mistake.

Does the statement "fields do not have non-zero nilpotents" depend on the law of excluded middle?

All proofs of this fact I can conjure rely on the dichotomy $a=0\vee a\neq 0$ along with the implication (for fields) that $a\neq 0\implies a$ invertbile. Moreover, in algebraic geometry it's possible to show the generic ring of Zariski topoi is internally a field (has the implication $a\neq 0\implies a$ invertible, but not necessarily excluded middle).

Is there some super simple example of a (commutative unitary) ring which is internally a field and has nilpotents?

**Added.** What about the statement "in a field, the only nilpotent is zero"?

**Remark.** The implication ($\neg (a=0)\implies a$ is invertible) is not of my invention; it is taken as the definition of a "ring of fractions" in section 2 of [this paper by Kock](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0022404976900025/1-s2.0-0022404976900025-main.pdf?_tid=2dd0403a-8ba0-11e6-9d42-00000aacb362&acdnat=1475743256_24db3216d2915ab8ebc0c5019e1e7f5b). Fields are defined analogously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $F$ is a field, I would interpret "No non-zero element is nilpotent" to mean simply that $(\forall x\in F)(x\ne 0 \implies (\forall n\in\mathbb{N})(x^n \ne 0)).$  The usual proof of this from the field axioms assumes $x\ne 0$ and proves that no power of $x$ is $0,$ which is constructive.

(The sentence $(\forall x\in F)(x=0 \,\lor\, (\forall n\in\mathbb{N})(x^n \ne 0))$ might be problematic, but that's a different sentence.)

---

As for the statement "In a field, the only nilpotent is zero," I think this depends how it's interpreted constructively.

(1) $\;(\forall x)\Big( \big((\exists n)(x^n=0)\big) \implies x=0 \Big)$ means that for every $x,$ if we have a witness $n$ that $x^n=0,$ then we can prove constructively that $x=0.$

(2) $\;\lnot (\exists x) \Big(\big((\exists n)(x^n=0)\big) \,\wedge\, x\ne0 \Big)$ means that we can derive a contradiction from the existence of a non-zero nilpotent.

(3) $\;(\forall x)\Big(x\ne 0 \implies \big((\forall n)(x^n \ne 0)\big) \Big)$ means that if we have a constructive proof that $x\ne 0,$ then, for every $n,$ we can produce constructively a constructive proof that $x^n\ne 0.$

(4) $\;(\forall x)\Big(x\ne 0 \implies \big(\lnot(\exists n)(x^n =0)\big) \Big)$ means the same thing as (2).

This is assuming I've unravelled everything correctly; it's tricky.  If one thinks through the proofs very carefully, one should be able to see which of these are always true constructively.

Comment: I've updated the question. Could you address the new portion as well?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the excluded middle to get a contradiction from a nilpotent in a field:

Suppose $a\ne 0$ but $a^n=0$ for some $n>1$. Then

$$ a = (a^{-1})^{n-1} \cdot a^n = (a^{-1})^{n-1} \cdot 0  = 0 $$
contradicting $a\ne 0$.

Comment: Don't proofs by contradiction rely on excluded middle somehow? (Excuse my ignorance)

Comment: @Arrow: Proofs _of a negative_ by contradiction are intuitionistically valid. (Assume $p$, derive a contraduction, ergo $\neg p$). This is _the_ way to prove negations constructively.

Comment: Proof of a positive claim by contradiction are not. (Assume $\neg p$, derive a contradiction, ergo $p$ -- only works classically).

Comment: @HenningMakholm You assume $(\exists a)(\exists n)(a\ne 0 \,\wedge\, a^n=0)$ and reach a contradiction.  All you can conclude from that is that $\lnot (\exists a)(\exists n)(a\ne 0 \,\wedge\, a^n=0),$ which doesn't seem to be the same thing constructively as $(\forall a)(\forall n) (\dots).$ To prove the universal quantification, which is what is needed, don't you need to do a direct proof, starting by assuming that $a\ne 0$ and $n\ge 1,$ and deriving the desired conclusion?

Comment: @MitchellSpector: Actually what I prove is $(\forall a)(\forall n>1)(a^n=0\to a=0)$, which is the "hard" direction of $(\forall a)(a=0 \leftrightarrow \exists n>1(a^n=0))$

Comment: You're right -- I think it would be better to phrase the proof that way, rather than as a proof by contradiction.  (I would take out "$a\ne 0$ but" at the beginning, and "contradicting $a\ne0$" at the end.)

Comment: @Mitchell: I don't think it matters much, even constructively -- especially since what was asked for is "fields do not have nonzero nilpotents" which sounds like a $\neg\exists$ anyway.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I can see the argument for that.  (It might still make sense in practice to avoid phrasing it as a proof by contradiction, since that raises a red flag that one has to think about, but that's a personal preference.)

Comment: @HenningMakholm I don't yet see how your argument shows that $x^n = 0\Rightarrow x=0$ - could you elaborate?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, you've literally proven $\neg(\neg a=0\wedge a^n=0)$. Are you claiming this unravels intuionistically to $a^n=0\to a=0$? I ask because I think it unravels to $a^n=0\to\neg\neg a=0$ instead.

Comment: @Hanno: Crap, you're right -- it actually only shows $x^n=0\land x\ne 0\to x=0$ ...

Comment: @VladimirSotirov: Yes, you're right. Fortunately that seems to be all that was actually asked for.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I've updated the question. Could you address the new portion as well?

Comment: This answer solves exactly what the OP had asked in the first place, so the recent downvotes don't make any sense at all. +1 instead.

Comment: @Hanno I also upvoted. The downvotes are beyond me. For what it's worth, somebody had temporarily downvoted the question earlier, so perhaps it's a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I think the intuitionistic definition of field you assume has to be disputed: First, you have $$(\ddagger):\qquad\forall s: \neg(s=0)\Rightarrow (s\text{ invertible})\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \forall s: \neg(s=0)\Leftrightarrow (s\text{ invertible}).$$ There, since $\neg\neg\neg\Phi\Leftrightarrow\neg\Phi$ is intuitionistically valid for any proposition $\Phi$, you get that
$$(\star)\qquad\left[\neg(s=0)\Leftrightarrow (s\text{ invertible})\right]\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \left[\neg\neg(s\text{ invertible})\Leftrightarrow (s\text{ invertible})\right].$$
It's questionable you want to impose this restriction, because e.g. it does not hold when interpreting the domain of $s$ as the structure sheaf ${\mathscr O}_X$ of a reduced scheme $X$, which internally you might want to think of as a field.

The reason the R.H.S. of $(\star)$ does not hold in this case is that the truth value of $(s\text{ invertible})$ is the (scheme-theoretic) non-vanishing locus $\{x\in X\ |\ s(x)\neq 0\text{ in }k(x)\}$ of $s$, so $\neg\neg(s\text{ invertible})$ holds iff the latter is dense in $X$, which is the case iff $s$ is regular.

On the other hand, the alternative implication/equivalence defining intuitionistic fields
$$(\dagger):\qquad\forall s: \neg(s\text{ invertible})\Rightarrow (s=0)\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \forall s: \neg(s\text{ invertible})\Leftrightarrow (s=0)$$
does hold for reduced schemes. Also, with this definition you can quickly prove that
$$s\text{ nilpotent}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad s=0$$
since $s\text{ nilpotent}\Rightarrow\neg(s\text{ invertible})$.

*Source:* [Ingo Blechschmidt's paper](https://github.com/iblech/internal-methods/raw/master/notes.pdf) is a very interesting and pleasant read on all of this.

Comment: This definition of a field is not of my invention - it is taken by Kock in [this paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0022404976900025/1-s2.0-0022404976900025-main.pdf?_tid=2dd0403a-8ba0-11e6-9d42-00000aacb362&acdnat=1475743256_24db3216d2915ab8ebc0c5019e1e7f5b) (see section 2). I would be glad if you could comment and illuminate more of the picture :)

Comment: @Arrow: To be honest, it's not a fully transparent picture in my head either, as I don't yet understand the relation and respective meaning of the two ways to define fields intuitionistically. I will edit as soon as I make some progress :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a model of a field in which it is not true that every nilpotent is zero.  The model will be the presheaf of commutative rings:
$$\mathbb{Z} / 4\mathbb{Z} \overset{\pi}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z}.$$

To see this satisfies the field axiom $\forall x, x \ne 0 \rightarrow \exists y, xy = 1$: first, it clearly holds at the level of $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$.  As for the level of $\mathbb{Z} / 4 \mathbb{Z}$, if $x \in \mathbb{Z} / 4 \mathbb{Z}$, suppose $x \ne 0$ evaluates to true at that level.  Then by definition of the interpretation of a negation, that implies $\pi(x) \ne 0$, so $x = 1 + 4\mathbb{Z}$ or $x = 3 + 4\mathbb{Z}$.  In either case, $x$ has an inverse at the level of $\mathbb{Z} / 4 \mathbb{Z}$.

However, $x = 2 + 4 \mathbb{Z}$ is nilpotent, whereas $x = 0$ does not evaluate to true at the level of $\mathbb{Z} / 4 \mathbb{Z}$.  (Note, though, that $\lnot(x \ne 0)$ does evaluate to true, as we would expect from the usual argument -- valid intuitionistically -- that in a field, products of nonzero elements are nonzero.)

Comment: Along similar lines, if you take $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \rightrightarrows \mathbb{Q}$ where the maps are the two projections, you get a field in which every nilpotent is zero, but still the field is not an integral domain in the sense of satisfying $\forall x, \forall y, xy = 0 \rightarrow x=0 \lor y=0$..